# How to pass BASH shell variables into AWK as a string in getline?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, text-processing

This is my script and it works perfect for one file:

```
awk 'BEGIN {while (getline < "eq5_1.gro") {if ($1 ~ /MGD/ && ($NF < 3.477 || $NF > 7.947 || $(NF-1) < 12.741 || $(NF-1) > 22.240)) name[$1]=$1}} {if ($1 != name[$1]) print}' 
eq5_1.gro | tee eq6_1.gro
```

I want to use this script on 100 files, so I wrote this script.

```
num=1
for num in {1..100}
do
    awk 'BEGIN {while (getline < "eq5_"'$num'".gro") {if ($1 ~ /MGD/ && ($NF < 3.477 || $NF > 7.947 || $(NF-1) < 12.741 || $(NF-1) > 22.240)) name[$1]=$1}} {if ($1 != name[$1]) print}'            eq5_$num.gro | tee eq6_$num.gro
done
```

I have a problem with this part of code

```
(getline < "eq5_"'$num'".gro")
```

How can I put here number as a string? I want to have here eq5_1.gro the eq5_2.gro etc. for  all 100 files
I also try this, didn't work

```
awk -v var="$num" 'BEGIN {while (getline < "eq5_"'$var'".gro")
```

Comment: What's the use of getline here?

Comment: What's the use of getline here?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude/unpolite, but I earnestly suggest you to take a time to carefully read an awk tutorial. You've been having difficulties with basic functionalities of it. That getline...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you ought to just be doing: `awk '...' eq5_*.gro`, but I'm not going to look to closely at your `awk` or question the wisdom of doing all your processing in a BEGIN clause (but I'll mention that it's bad practice).  But you can do:

```
for num in {1..100}; do
    awk -v file="eq5_${num}.gro" 'BEGIN {while (getline < file) ...} '
done
```

Comment: Don't work. I have an error
Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU options style] -f program_file [-] file ...

gawk is the language for scanning and merging patterns.
By default, the program reads the standard input and writes the standard output.
./delete_water.sh: line 13: $ 'BEGIN {\ n \ t \ twhile (getline <count {\ n \ t \ t \ tif ($ NF <3,477 || $ NF> 7.947 || $ (NF-1 ) <12.741 || $ (NF-1)> 22.240) \ n \ t \ t \ t \ tname [$ 1] = $ 1 \ n \ t \ t \ t} \ n \ t \ t} \ n \ t {if ($ 1! = name [$ 1]) print} ': no ​​command found

Comment: The problem you are having is not in awk.  It looks like your script is trying to execute the awk command instead of passing it as an argument to awk.  In other words, it's a usage error, as indicated in the error message.

Comment: It works! I found another error in my script. Thank you so much YOU ARE BOSS!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Reformatting for readability

```sh
awk '
    BEGIN {
        while (getline < "eq5_1.gro") {
            if ($1 ~ /MGD/ && ($NF < 3.477 || $NF > 7.947 || $(NF-1) < 12.741 || $(NF-1) > 22.240)) 
                name[$1]=$1
        }
    }
    {if ($1 != name[$1]) print}
' eq5_1.gro
```

So you want to print the lines that *don't* match that condition?

Your awk command can be greatly simplified, and you don't need to process the file twice.

```
awk '! ($1 ~ /MGD/ && ($NF < 3.477 || $NF > 7.947 || $(NF-1) < 12.741 || $(NF-1) > 22.240))' eq5_1.gro
```

Refer to the [awk info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info)